# Should I not be using Django per-site caching?

Tags: django, caching

I've just enabled Django's per-site caching in my web application (using Redis as my cache backend) and have immediately run into a problem.  My site includes a user profile page that shows the user's photo and their bio.  I also have a form that allows them to change their photo and/or bio.  If the user uploads a new photo, I create a new unique name for that photo.  As you would expect, when the user goes to that form and uploads a new photo and I redisplay their profile page so that they can review it before submitting it with a new photo or bio, the page shows their old photo because I have per-site caching enabled.  Can I disable caching for specific views (i.e. for situations like this) or must I disable per-site caching and implement it on a view-by-view basis?  This is my first experience ever with caching and I'm not sure what approach I should take.  I have another view/template that shows all of the users who are currently logged in and I anticipate having the same problem there, namely that their old photo will continue to be displayed after they've changed it.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Here's a generic suggestion: use the approach that suits most cases and then specifically enable/disable (depending on the approach) where required. You can also follow a "cache invalidation" strategy, where certain actions clear certain caches.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is, with caching enabled, if the user goes to their "Change profile" form page, changes their bio, submits the form, and I re-render the form to show the new bio content, why isn't that content displayed on the form page?  The page content did change so why is Django re-rendering the previous form/page?  Shouldn't it see that the page's content changed and therefore not fetch the page from the cache?  Thanks.

Comment: In Django docs, it looks like modifying the page does not invalidate the cache. There is always a moneypatching strategy, to use a querysing based on the last modification `/profile?whatever=timestampstring`, ugly, I know.

Comment: Or try the `must_revalidate` parameter, like `@cache_control(must_revalidate=True, max_age=3600)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of reading since I posted this question yesterday and I'll share what I've learned.  These are my *impressions* of how you should approach caching based on what I've read, not on any experience I have.  Therefore, I may get some things wrong.

First, you shouldn't just turn caching on as a panacea for performance, especially if you don't know what you're doing.  Caching adds more complexity to your stack, it creates another point of failure, and apparently it can sometimes cause weird problems that are difficult to troubleshoot.  You're probably better off not doing any caching until you've figured out how to measure your website's performance, have done some profiling, and have in fact demonstrated that you have a performance problem.  From what I've read, you'd be better off focusing on optimizing your database queries and minimizing your page weights before you try caching via Django.  If you want to do any caching at all right off that bat, look at caching your images, stylesheets, and JavaScript via your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc.).

With respect to my question, I think I had the wrong notion of how caching works.  When I enabled "per-site" caching in Django, what I think I said to Django was "store every response to every page request in your Redis cache until the cache fills up and starts evicting things."  If a page is requested and that page is still in the cache, the cache isn't magically going to know whether or not that page has changed and then go fetch the updated version (if it has).  It will continue returning that cached page no matter how many times I change it (unless it's evicted).

What I did do just as a test was to apply the @never_cache decorator to the view in question.  That fixed the problem I was having.  However, as Lorenzo alluded to, apply caching on a case-by-case basis is probably a better approach.  If you want to cache a particular view, use the @cache_page decorator.  If you want to cache a portion of a template, use {% cache %}.  Cache actual data that is expensive to compute via Django's low-level API "django.core.cache.caches".  And if you want to do caching based on cache expiration and/or validation, use Django's "Conditional View Processing" feature via the @condition decorator.

If you're totally new to caching, I highly recommend that you read Mark Nottingham's [Caching Tutorial](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) and Ryan Tomayko's [Things Caches Do](http://2ndscale.com/rtomayko/2008/things-caches-do).

I hope this helps!